# extern function declared locally

Tags: c++, function, local, extern

Say I have a class which inside one of its functions there is an `extern` function:

```
A::foo(){
  extern void fun();
  fun();
}
```

My question is if there is some other place to put the decleration of the `extern` function besides locally? Say, inside the decleration of the class in the `.h` file?

Answer (score 2):

Function declarations are "extern" by default, so you can simply say:

```
void fun();
class::foo(){
  fun();
}
```

Comment: Even if i didn't import the file where fun() sits?

Comment: @or.nomore: The definition of fun() should be in a .c or .cpp file.  The declaration of fun() should be in a .h or .hpp file.